# Is this common practice to avoid key not found in a dictionary

Tags: python

I was wondering, whether the following style is a common practice to avoid key not found in a dictionary?

```
# default is 0
value = my_dic[100] if 100 in my_dic else 0
```

Comment: See Chris' answer below. You should check the python official documentation while in doubt, it's very well-written and complete! The most helpful set of language docs I've seen.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
value = my_dic.get(100, 0)
```

Comment: this is interesting, i've never seen it before, @chris. could you eleaborate just a bit? is this a python 3+ construct?

Comment: @Ramy: `help(dict.get)`: `D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.`

Comment: AFAICT, `.get()` has been around for a as long as there have been `dict` s.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to access a key that is not in the dictionary, python will raise an exception that will crash your program. Instead of this, you should "catch" the exception and do something more graceful.

it's better practice to catch the exception:

```
try: 
  value = my_dic[100]
except KeyError:
   print("key not found in dictionary") #or handle the error more elegantly
```

I haven't read the article, but you can learn more here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling

Comment: `except KeyError`, please, not `except`.

Comment: serious? i thought trying to hook a exception handle will have impact in performance.

Comment: Actually, this faster than `dict.get` if the key is in the dict.  but not by very much, but slower by an order of magnitude when its not in the dict.  If you know the key is in the dict the vast majority of the time, use regular subscripting.  If the key is likely not in the dict, use `dict.get`.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: in this situation if I'm just trying to get a default I'd always use `dict.get`, simply because it's shorter and more obvious. Why `try..except` when you can just `get()`? It would need to be a pretty significant performance gain doing it the verbose way before I ever would do it that way.

Comment: @Chris: Like I said.  You would not use dict.get if you expect the key is in the dict.  dict[] outperforms dict.get when the KeyError happens less than about 1 in 200 attempts.  You should use whichever form most closely agrees with your expectations.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the "default value" everywhere, consider [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) as a possible alternative. (A factory/callback approach offers a good bit of flexibility with the "default value".)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

It is valid python syntax, however I would say that according to [Python Coding Style Guidelines](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) You should structure your if else statements like so,

```
if <condition>:
    <statements>
else:
    <statements>
```

Comment: Please don't do `if(condition):`.  Just do `if condition:`. *We don't need gratuitous parentheses.*

Comment: sorry, i mean <condition> but i was trying to type fast because I was assuming that it would get answered quickly.

Comment: The OP's code is a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html?highlight=conditional#conditional-expressions), not an `if` [compound] statement -- so for at least that reason, your answer isn't especially relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
first_name = params.get('first_name', None)
if first_name:
    profile.first_name = first_name
```